# Ensuring character is escaped with Python Regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I have some code in Python 3 that looks like this:

```
import re

searchChar = string1[0]
re.finditer(searchChar, a_string)
```

So the idea is to find the indices of all occurrences of a character in a string.

The problem is that `string1` could be anything, so if it's something normal like `string1 = 'cat'` or `string1 = 'dog'`, then everything is fine.

But if it starts with a regular expression control character then you have a problem.  For example, if you have `string1 = *hello`, then `searchChar` is `'*'`, and `findIter` will return an error since `'*'` is an invalid regex.

In my scenario I'm always searching for a character literal.  So is there a way to ensure that `searchChar` is escaped (i.e. `'\*'`) if and only if it needs to be?

Comment: seems like regex gets more in the way that it helps. What about simple string search?

Comment: Use [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape)

Comment: You do not need `re` for finding occurrence of a character in a string, something like `string.find` should suffice. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Niemmi's comment was the answer I needed.  Looks like [re.escape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Do a plain string search. If you want to count occurrences of a substring, `str` instances provide the `count`  method for that.

```
>>> '*|*|'.count('*')
2
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in the question.  I'm trying to find the **indices** of each occurrence of the character, not just the number of occurrences.  I updated the question to reflect that.